# How to select item from list box using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

> How can i select option from below drop down list. I tried with xpath
>   or id but it does not work.
>
> ```
>    java.util.List<WebElement> option = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentOne_engage_admin_page_user_engage_admin_user_ddlUserType_listbox']"));
> ```

```
        for(WebElement select : option){
            if("Administrator".equals(select.getText()));
            select.click();
        }

    <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="ctl00_ContentOne_engage_admin_page_user_engage_admin_user_ddlUserType_listbox" aria-live="off" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="ctl00_ContentOne_engage_admin_page_user_engage_admin_user_ddlUserType_option_selected" aria-selected="true">Enter User Type...</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">AdminOne</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Read Only</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">REST API</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Publisher</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">API User</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: did you facing any exceptions, plz provide that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it, you seem to be making a list of the `<ul>` elements, which will only be the one element. I'm assuming you want to make a list of the `<li>` elements which you can do using the following code

```
java.util.List<WebElement> option = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'k-item')]"));
```